# Fetch attribute value as Variable in GTM

Tags: css, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

Hello I have this code on my website that gives the query of a site search in the attribute 'value'
In this case, it is the word 'disjoncteur' that  want in my variable in GTM.

```
<div class="dfd-searchbox-main">
<input type="search" name="search[query]" value="disjoncteur" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" class="dfd-searchbox-input" id="dfd-searchbox-id-MIkFo-input" placeholder="Chercher…" dfd-value-indices="" dfd-hook="Input">
<div class="dfd-searchbox-autocomplete"></div>
```

What should i do to fetch that value in a variable ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A general solution would be making a custom JS variable in GTM looking like this:

```js
function(){
  return document.querySelector("input[type='search']").value;
}
```

However, it's a little bit awkward due to how universal it attempts to be. And realistically, you likely only need that search value on the CTA click, so a relative path from that CTA could have been used through a `{{Click Element}}` variable. That would be a cleaner solution.

And, of course, the best solution would be asking front-end devs to give you the value with a dataLayer push so that you wouldn't need to rely on the html structure of the page to get your info.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I acheived to create a dom element variable by inserting the class of the element into ID and the attribute "value" as the attribute, it works like a charm.